# Documentclass: Report + Nomencl package

Tags: report, nomencl

I am using sharelatex and pdfLatex as my compiler.

When I change my documentclass to article the nomenclature shows but if I have report as documentclass I don't see the nomenclature, example code below

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section*{Main equations}
\begin{equation}
a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%

\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%
The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
follows easily.
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Works fine with both here (on ShareLaTeX).

Comment: Of course, with `report` the nomenclature heading is a `\chapter`, so it starts on the next page.

Comment: Hmm okey that is weird. Could you share your code? Or some setting I am missing? Doesn't work when I try with a local compiler either

Comment: You could try with a new project, though I don't know if it would make a difference. I just made https://www.sharelatex.com/read/sntnqztrpfpp and hit the compile button once. As you can see, the nomenclature is there on page 3.

Comment: I see, there must be some fishy problem in with imported packages or something. Thanks I will look further!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved the problem.

In Sharelatex I had my main.tex file within a folder. Remove this folder (i.e. have main.tex in the root) fixed the problem.

I guess it has something to do with tex having problem to find the .nlo file or something similar.

Cheers